# C - Declaring a global array within a function not possible. Other solutions?

Tags: c, arrays

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I need a global array with a length that is dependent on a variable (NumOfRequests).  That variable is set within a function.   I don't think it's possible to declare a global array within a function as I tried to do in the following code:

```
static uint8 NumOfRequests;

typedef struct
{
    uint16 IndexToRequest;
    GdXRequestData_ts RequestData;
    bool RequestSent;
} GdRequests;

static void SetupRequestStructures( void )
{
    uint8 i;

    for( i = 0; EepromData_ps.GD_Indices[i] != 0xFFFF; i++ )
    {
        NumOfRequests = i + 1;
    }
    GdRequests Requests[NumOfRequests];
    for( i = 0; i < NumOfRequests; i++ )
    {
        Requests[i].IndexToRequest = EepromData_ps.GD_Indices[i];
    }

}
```

It's not possible to declare an array and later decide what length it should be or change its length, as far as I know.

So does anyone know another solution for how to declare a global array with a length based on a variable that is set within a function?

Any feedback is appreciated.  If you upvote or downvote, tell me why so I can improve with future questions.

Comment: Read about *pointers* and how to allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: It is possible to declare a *local* array of run-time size in C, as in your example. It is not possible to do that for a *global* array. So, what kind of array do you need: global or local? In the title you mention a global one, but in the code you declare a local one. What do you mean by "declare a global array within a function"?

Comment: @AnT What I meant by "declare a global array within a function" is that I  wanted to declare the array within that function, but have it be global, aka accessible to other functions within the same source file.  but I realized that's not possible.  That's why I prefaced the code with "I don't think this is possible."

Comment: Use a pointer and malloc?  It's not actually an array, but can be treated as one in most ways.

Comment: C doesn't actually have a concept of "global". Scope and lifetime are separate concepts. When you say "global", do you mean you want the array to exist for the entire execution of the program (that's static storage duration, or static lifetime), or do you mean that you want its name visible to other functions (that's file scope), or both? Note that an array with static lifetime cannot have a size that depends on the value of a variable. Variables aren't initialized until after such an array is created.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic memory allocation to perform this task.  Look at [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and [free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/).  Here's a simple example of dynamic memory allocation on a global array of structs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _MyStruct
{
    int a;  
    int b;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct *g_Array = NULL;

void populatearray(MyStruct *array, int length)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        array[i].a = i;
        array[i].b = i;
    }
}

void printstructs(MyStruct *array, int length)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("array[%d].a = %d\narray[%d].b = %d\n\n", i, array[i].a, i,  array[i].b);
    }
}

int main()
{
    g_Array = malloc(50 * sizeof(MyStruct));
    if(!g_Array)
    {
        puts("Malloc failed");
        return 0;
    }
    populatearray(g_Array, 50);
    printstructs(g_Array, 50);
    free(g_Array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to `{perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}` on failure of `malloc`

Comment: Better: `err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s: %d: malloc", __func__, __LINE__");`